# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp start from left bottom corner

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I try to use method `[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:];` for change some images and hide some elements with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` (and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown` in the reverse situation). It works, but I would like to start flipping from the bottom left corner.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `transform` of your container view (the one that has the transition applied to it) to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1)` to flip the transition effect, and apply the same `transform` on its content view to flip the content back.

Comment: Unfortunately, to no avail. Elucidated that the angle varies depending on the orientation of the interface